# How to remove zero before valid number in input text field - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to remove or trim zero as first or before the valid number in input text field.

I have a text field and am restricting the user to enter only numbers. When I enter the value as "0145" it should read as "145".

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="number" required="required" numbers-only="numbers-only" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
           // this next if is necessary for when using ng-required on your input. 
           // In such cases, when a letter is typed first, this parser will be called
           // again, and the 2nd time, the value will be undefined
           if (inputValue == undefined) return '' 
           var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
           if (transformedInput!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
              modelCtrl.$render();
           }         

           return transformedInput;         
       });
     }
   };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.number = ''
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/DwKZh/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/^[^1-9]*|[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is slightly wrong.  It should be:

```
var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/^0*/g, '')
```

This will replace all the 0's at the beginning of the string